# java.nio.file.InvalidPathException

Tags: java, char

I am making a minecraft server...and I have a IllegalChar error
Here is the log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4: file:FOO\server.properties
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.toPath(Unknown Source)
    at com.sukkit.Info.loadProperties(FOO2.java:31)
    at com.sukkit.Sukit.main(FOO.java:17)
```

Here is the server.properties file:

```
generator-settings=
allow-nether=true
level-name=world
enable-query=false                       --FOURTH LINE
allow-flight=false
server-port=25565
level-type=DEFAULT
enable-rcon=false
force-gamemode=false
level-seed=
server-ip=
max-build-height=256
spawn-npcs=true
white-list=false
spawn-animals=true
hardcore=false
texture-pack=
online-mode=true
pvp=true
difficulty=1
gamemode=0
max-players=20
spawn-monsters=true
generate-structures=true
view-distance=10
motd=A Minecraft Server
```

And here is the code:

```
File extFile = new File("server.properties");//create external file
File inFile = new File(MAINFOO.getCodeBase(*/I HAVE CREATED THIS METHOD IN THE MAIN FOO CLASS*/)+"server.properties");//create internal file
if (!extFile.exists()){
    OutputStream out;
    try {out = new FileOutputStream(extFile);
    Files.copy(inFile.toPath(), out);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Sukit.logE(e.toString());
        Sukit.getLogger().severe("ERROR: FILE IS CORRUPT...PLEASE REDOWNLOAD SUKIT");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the MAINFOO.getCodeBase() method:

```
public static String getCodeBase() {
    String i = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("server.properties").toString();
    String is[] = i.split("server.properties");
    logD(is[0]);
    return is[0];
}
```

I do not have a single : in my properties file... HELP

Comment: You seems to be passing file path containing `file://` which is why it is failing, please add the code where you call the load method

Comment: What is the result of `MAINFOO.getCodeBase(*/I HAVE CREATED THIS METHOD IN THE MAIN FOO CLASS*/)+"server.properties")` ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the file.  The problem is the file name: `file:FOO\server.properties`. Notice that at index 4 (character 5), you have a `:`. Instead, you should just use `FOO\server.properties` and omit the `file:`.